# marking the spire’s completion on Tuesday

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following passage, does "marking the spire's completion" imply the spire has been completed and thus contradict the first sentence?

> Set to become the world’s second tallest building **upon its completion next year**, Merdeka 118 now stands higher than China’s 2,073-foot Shanghai Tower and is dwarfed only by the Burj Khalifa in Dubai. At a ceremony **marking the spire’s completion on Tuesday**, Malaysian Prime Minister Ismail Sabri Yaakob described the project as an “iconic tower for the future.”

Comment: It does seem to on first reading, but presumably the spire which has been completed is only a part of the building.

Comment: What is the source of the text?

Comment: It's from a CNN article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A '[spire](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spire)' is a tall, pointed structure on top of a building. When a building has a spire it is usually the uppermost point.

The building Merdeka 118 has a spire. Without the spire, it would not be as tall as the Shanghai Tower, but is taller with it.

The first statement is speaking about the overall completion of the building, but the second is speaking about only the spire, which is significant to the statement about its height, so there is no contradiction.

[image]